# how to spring boot application source code from jar file on kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

```
➜  ~ kubectl exec -it my_pod /bin/sh -n my_team
sh-4.2$ ls
elastic-apm-agent.jar  logs  run.sh  my-app.jar
sh-4.2$
```

I want to see my application's source code (my-app.jar). This is a spring boot application. How can i see it?

Summary - I want to view a controller file of my spring boot project which is deployed on k8 pod.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this? What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: That `.jar` file contains the compiled byte-code of the application, not its source code.  You could probably copy it out and use a decompiler on it, but that doesn't sound like what you're after.

Comment: I want to view a controller file of my spring boot project which is deployed on k8 pod

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, it contains complied byte code of application, but i want to check source code.

Answer (score 2):

For compiled languages (Java, C++, Rust, Go, ...) a typical Docker image won't contain its source code, and that source code won't be present at all in an environment like Kubernetes.  You need to find some other path to retrieve it, like the original source-code repository.

This differs from interpreted languages [Python, Javascript, Ruby, ...] where the source code is required to run the application, and for those languages it can be easily extracted from the image or the deployment environment.

Comment: If you don't have access to the sources you can load the class files in the jar into a Java decompiler.